# Letter space align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, letterspacing

So I am writing an assignment for that requires me to list out a permutation of letters.

I currently have something like this

[image]

How do I make it so that each letter in the second row is directly below the letter in the first row?

Comment: use a two row tabular

Answer (score 4):

Use a mono-spaced font which sets lower and upper case letters at the same width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\ttfamily
  a b c d e \\
  E D C B A
}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, arrange the letters using a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\ttfamily\begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
  a & b & c & d & e \\
  E & D & C & B & A
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

This latter approach works with non-mono-spaced fonts and you can adjust the `\tabcolsep` to space the letters appropriately.